# REGEX to trim a string after 180 characters and before |

Tags: regex, notepad++

In a pipe separated text file I need to trim the first column to no more than 180 characters.

If there is less than 180 characters I'll keep whatever is there.

Now the ugly part... I'm trying to do this in Notepad++ which means I can use find/replace with regex but not actual code. Not sure how to do a regex "If you hit a pipe before 180 you don't need to trim anything."

Comment: I don't have access to Notepad++, but in most regex variations, `[^|]{0,180}` will match 0 to 180 non-pipe characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^([^|]{0,180})[^|]+(.*)$
```

and this as the replace:

```
\1\2
```

Here's a screen shot of the Find/Replace dialog in Notepad++:

[image: Notepad++ regex]

I tested it with this dummy data:

http://pastie.org/3855302

And it resulted with this output:

http://pastie.org/3855308

Comment: Appears Notepad isn't playing nice with your recommendation for some reason. I appreciate your suggestion though!

Comment: @Korak I downloaded and installed Notepad++ and tested it, and it works perfectly. Can you give some sample data you're working on?

Comment: @Korak I've edited the answer to show it working for me in Notepad++, including screenshot to compare to your own

Comment: Thanks! That works for me perfectly. There had been an update for Notepad++ that I hadn't updated too that kept it from working when I first tried it. Thank you so much for all your help!