# RegEx - Extract string from character 91 up to character 180 and delete everything before and after

Tags: regex

I am trying to extract character 91 to 180 from this text:

> Exosphere -6° Reg. fra Deuter er den perfekte sovepose til dig, der har det med at stritte med arme og ben, når du sover, og føler dig lidt hæmmet i en almindelig mumiesovepose. Den er nemlig fuld af elastikker, som tillader soveposen at blive op til 25% bredere, end den umiddelbart ser ud til at være.

So that the output will look like this:

> itte med arme og ben, når du sover, og føler dig lidt hæmmet i en almindelig mumiesovepose

I am using this expression which I found here on SO [REGEX to trim a string after 180 characters and before |](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435574/regex-to-trim-a-string-after-180-characters-and-before):

Replace

```
    ^([^|]{91,180})[^|]+(.*)$
```

with

```
    \1\2
```

It is doing some of the job this is the output:

> Exosphere -6° Reg. fra Deuter er den perfekte sovepose til dig, der har det med at stritte med arme og ben, når du sover, og føler dig lidt hæmmet i en almindelig mumiesovepose

So now I need to remove everything before character 91.

Comment: It sounds as if you wanted `^[\s\S]{90}([\s\S]{90})[\s\S]*` and replace with `\1`

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, used this one `^.{90}(.{90}).*` and replaced with `$1`

Comment: Where are you using it? Note `.` does not match any char by default in most cases.

Comment: I am using it in DatafeedWatch, it is a feed tool for ecommerce product feeds.

Comment: I would suggest `[\s\S]` still. It seems a JS regex.

Comment: Don't know if I am allowed to ask a follow up question on this, but if I want to put a punctuation mark after the last word within the 90 char. How do I do that? Ex. if the word 'mumiesovepose' was cut in two, then I would like to put a punctuation mark after the word 'almindelig' and end the string there.

Comment: Something like `^[\s\S]{90}([\s\S]{0,90})\b(?!\w)[\s\S]*` => `$1.`?

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot mate! I have clicked the check mark for your answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point here is that you need to match the first 90 chars, then match *and capture* another 90 chars into Group 1, and then just match the rest of the string, then replace with a backreference to Group 1 value.

You may use

```
^[\s\S]{90}([\s\S]{90})[\s\S]*
```

Or, if there are no line breaks, a more "regular"

```
^.{90}(.{90}).*
```

patterns. Replace with `$1`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iH92mK/1)